# Deactivate subscripts and superscripts raising / lowering in latex mode

Tags: latex

On a new install, I noticed that Emacs systematically lowers or raises what it identifies as subscripts or superscripts (sometimes correctly, sometimes incorrectly...) due to the presence of `_` or `^` in `latex-mode`.
Syntax highlighting is enough for me, and I do not want Emacs to do any WYSIWYG mess, so I need to deactivate this.

I found several old notes that addressed other causes of this, and tried them all, but it seems my issue is a different one.

I have GNU emacs-25.2.1 (under Linux gentoo).
I am not using any of the "advanced modes" (yatex, auctex) as they do even more visual things that I do not like. I am just using the stock `latex-mode`, which used to be fine for my purpose.

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for `tex-fontify-script`, which you can customize, or just set manually via:

```
(setq tex-fontify-script nil)
```

Comment: +1 - though you need to set it to `nil` instead of `t` to get rid of the funky subscripts and superscripts.

Comment: In addition to set `tex-fontify-script` to `nil`, I also had to change `font-latex-fontify-script` and set it to `nil`.

Comment: @Olivier: that's only if you're using `font-latex` (which comes with AUCTeX, IIUC) instead of the "builtin" font-lock rules.  In your case, I'd guess that setting `tex-fontify-script` doesn't actually have any effect.

Comment: @Stefan. This worked for me. Thanks!  Additional question: How does one get latexmode to stop highlighting the carat and underscore characters with a different color?

Answer (score 1):

With 26.1 on macOS Mojave, I found that the following two lines in `custom-set-variables` did the trick (I actually found them via the customisation browser):

```
 '(tex-font-script-display (quote (-0.0 0.0)))
 '(tex-suscript-height-ratio 1.0)
```

The first defines the amount by which the sub/superscript is lowered/raised.
The second defines how tall the super/subscript characters are with respect to the default.